# How to change color path inside the background with color in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I wanna change this yellow circled area to the color it's on (the reddish color). How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Shape Builder tool.

1. Select both shapes
2. Choose the Shape Builder tool
3. Draw with the tool over the part you want removed.

[image]